# hubot doesn't load my hubot-scripts configuration

Tags: hubot

I've set up a hubot server, version `2.7.1`. Here's the dependencies section of my `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
  "hubot": ">= 2.6.0 < 3.0.0",
  "hubot-scripts": ">= 2.5.0 < 3.0.0",
  "hubot-hipchat": "~2.6.4"
},
```

When it starts, it loads the scripts in `scripts/` but seems to ignore the collection I've put in `hubot-scripts.json`. Here's the first part of that file:

```
["shipit.coffee", "sudo", "9gag", "abstract"
```

With verbose startup logs, you can see that shipit.coffee is included (one of the defaults), but none of the rest are:

```
[Tue Feb 25 2014 10:59:46 GMT-0800 (PST)] DEBUG Loading hubot-scripts from /path/node_modules/hubot-scripts/src/scripts
[Tue Feb 25 2014 10:59:46 GMT-0800 (PST)] DEBUG Parsing help for /path/node_modules/hubot-scripts/src/scripts/shipit.coffee
[Tue Feb 25 2014 10:59:46 GMT-0800 (PST)] DEBUG Loading external-scripts from npm packages
```

There are about 460 files in the `node_modules/hubot-scripts/src/scripts/` directory, and it includes the four given in my `hubot-scripts.json` file. All I can assume is that it isn't reading that file.. or something.

[This documentation diff](https://github.com/github/hubot/commit/2593afef2b4748686374cd745a1336b24fcec633) makes me think I haven't missed something, [there's an old issue](https://github.com/github/hubot/issues/391) that was patched eons ago too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding `.coffee` extension to all your script names in `hubot-scripts.json`:

```
["shipit.coffee", "sudo.coffee", "9gag.coffee", "abstract.coffee"
```

Comment: perfect. Thanks for finding that, my [rubber duck](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/rubber-duck-problem-solving.html) failed me.